# Does ng-transclude stop event propagation in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, transclusion

The problem occurs when I try to send an event from my directive to a nested directive via the $scope object. E.g. `$scope.broadcast('event')` the child directive doesn't receive the event, but when I use the $rootScope object it works e.g. `$rootScope.broadcast('event')`.

**TL;DR**: Why doesn't this work: http://plnkr.co/edit/27qYiHOilpVABSwMI0Fb?p=preview when this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/o91yFKnQzHp7edUTTkJE?p=preview

**EDIT: In angular.js version 1.3.0 and up this is no longer a issue!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive(s) uses `ng-transclude`.  From the docs:

> In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope.

This is what your scope hierarchy looks like:

[image: Scope hierarchy]

- 003 is the isolated scope of directive `one`
- 004 is the transclusion scope where the `two` elements live in
- 005 is the scope of the first directive `two`
- 006 is the transclusion scope of the first directive `two`

So as you can see the scope of `two` is not a child scope of `one`.

Comment: THAT'S IT:-) Then I can use `$scope.$$nextSibling.$broadcast('send');` instead and everything works: http://plnkr.co/edit/0QxgTUl7e1DTQbsEccIX?p=preview

Comment: From what I'm able to understand the $$ properties are private. Is there are better way to send events to the transcluded child?

Answer (score 2):

> Transclusion creates an 'isolate' scope, but the transclusion is not a
>   child, but a sibling of the 'isolate' scope.

(From the source code)

There is no parent <-> child relationship. Therefore $broadcast, $emit won't work because $broadcast requires children and $emit requires a parent that you think is a sibling.

There are a lot of great explanations for the problem here that have probably encouraged you to rethink the way your controllers are organized, as well as how you are using ng-transclude. In case you want another solution, I wrote a tiny directive that solves the interaction between two directives to create the parent <-> child hierarchy. Use at your own risk and I hope this helps! :)

https://gist.github.com/meanJim/1c3339bde5cbeac6417d

Answer (score 0):

It's because you gave the directives isolate scope. Remove the scope parameter from the directive if you want it to have nested scope with parent elements. Or you can define on the scope the properties and values from the parent scope that you would like to pass to the directive's scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aMEpo5zZ76rfMj7Khnoy?p=preview

Comment: But it's only the parent scope that has an isolated scope. The child scope is set to `true`. And don't think you can to explicitly define events in the child scope. (PS: The plnkr you linked to doesn't seem to work either, nothing happens when I click the button)

Comment: try now, forgot to save it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that by removing the scope parameter you are implicitly setting it to false, which in turn means that the directives don't have scope. And this means that everything you do happens in the outermost scope (rootScope in this instance). And this means that you can't have more than one directive on the page: http://plnkr.co/edit/D1rIwOKWRJDqgjVcP9yu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If the scope of `FirstCtrl` is parent to the scope of `SecondCtrl`, you should use **$broadcast** method in the `FirstCtrl`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myAppControllers', [])
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('UPDATE_CHILD');
  })
  .controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('UPDATE_CHILD', function() {
      // do something useful here;
    });
  });
```

**if there’s no parent/child relation between scopes, you should inject $rootScope** into the FirstCtrl and broadcast the event into other controllers (including SecondCtrl) and their corresponding (child in this case) $scope’s:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myAppControllers', [])
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('UPDATE_ALL');
  });
```

Comment: Shouldn't this structure imply a parent/child scope relationship `<one><two/></one>` where the *two* scope is a child of the *one* scope?

Comment: E.g. If i broadcast in the *one* scope it should propagate to the *two* scope?